# wrong number of arguments in Net::HTTP request

Tags: ruby, http, rspec, sinatra, webmock

In a Sinatra application, I'm trying to make my own wrapper around `Net::HTTP`, but I'm stuck at one of my tests. I'm using Webmock to stub a request and pass it to the `request` method of `Net::HTTP`. I do the testing with RSpec. The error I'm getting is:

```
 Failure/Error: client.request(request)

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/webmock-2.1.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:279:in `method'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/webmock-2.1.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:279:in `request_signature_from_request'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/webmock-2.1.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:75:in `request'
 # ./lib/net_http.rb:19:in `request'
 # ./spec/net_http_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:236:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:236:in `block in run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:478:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:435:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:478:in `block in run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:478:in `run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:435:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:478:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:233:in `run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:581:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:577:in `map'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:577:in `run_examples'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:543:in `run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:119:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:119:in `map'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1680:in `with_suite_hooks'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block in run_specs'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:117:in `run_specs'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:93:in `run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Line 279 of `net_http.rb` (the first line of the stack) is:

```
method = request.method.downcase.to_sym
```

which is inside the method:

```
module WebMock
  module NetHTTPUtility

    def self.request_signature_from_request(net_http, request, body = nil)
      ...
```

which is called in line 75 of the same file:

```
def request(request, body = nil, &block)
  request_signature = WebMock::NetHTTPUtility.request_signature_from_request(self, request, body)
```

which is the method I am calling on my client. These are my files:

**net_http.rb**

```
class NetHttp

  def initialize(client)
    @client = client
  end

  def request(request)
    client.request(request)
  end

  private

  attr_reader :client

end
```

**net_http_spec.rb**

```
describe "NetHttp" do

  let(:client)   {Net::HTTP.new(VERIFY_URL.host, VERIFY_URL.port)}
  let(:net_http) {NetHttp.new(client)}

  it "sends a get request" do
    request  = request_with_path
    response = net_http.request(request)
    expect(response.code).to eq("200")
  end

  def request_with_path
    request = stub_request(:get, VERIFY_URL)
      .with(:headers => {
        'Accept'=>'*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
        'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'
        })
      .to_return(:status => 200, :body => '{"hello": "world"}', :headers => {})

    class << request
      attr_accessor :path
    end

    request.path = VERIFY_URL.request_uri
    request
  end

end
```

The last part where I add an attribute on the fly was to solve another error. It feels a bit like a dirty hack. Maybe there is a better way to do all this, that will also prevent me from doing that?

And in my **spec_helper.rb** I added the line:

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

I have put the contents of the request inside the `request` method and everything seems to be ok, I have also used a double of `Net::HTTPRequest` instead of a webmock stub, but I get the same error. I don't want to stub the client because that's my system under test. I have also looked at the code of the `request` method in the Ruby docs. I don't understand... where is that error coming from and how to solve it?

Comment: Try running rspec with the -b option (by default rspec hides portions of the backtrace not from your app which can make you look in the wrong place)

Comment: @FrederickCheung I have updated the error message.

Comment: Looks like your fake request object doesn't have a `method` method so it is calling the `method` method from Object which does indeed expect an argument

Comment: I went down that path but it just keeps asking for something else, like a `body_stream` with a `read` method and etc., etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the return value of `stub_request` as you are. You can construct an instance of `Net::HTTP::Request` as normal.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... I need to pass a request object to the request method. The way it is going to be created in production is like this: `request = Net::HTTP::Get.new VERIFY_URL.request_uri`, but if I pass that, Webmock alerts me that Real HTTP connections are disabled. I don't want to have any calls to `new` inside the method because I want to use dependency injection.

Comment: Webmock docs suggest that should be fine. Perhaps you are stubbing the request incorrectly? (Eg what is VERIFY_URL)

Comment: VERIFY_URL is a string that contains an URI object with the URL that I would like to connect to. My understanding is that webmock will catch requests to that URL and return the stubbed response.

Comment: It looks like it is an actual URI object which may not be what webmock is expecting - docs imply it's just a string

Comment: I finally understood your answer. When I do `response = net_http.request(request)` it automagically uses the stub. So if I remove the first line of the test and the assignment of the stub, it works :)